# how to use if to test whether a value is in a list in mysql?

Tags: mysql, iif-function

Below are part of the code in a procedure:

```
if p_vendor_id is null then set v_msg := 'Error: parameters are not valid'
    elseif p_vendor_id not in (select vendor_id from p_plants.vendors) then
        set v_msg := 'Error: vendor id parameter is not a vendor in our tables'
```

I am getting a syntax error with `else if...not in`. How can I test whether a value is in a list?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the whole error?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not right, you should use semicolon and `end if`

```
if p_vendor_id is null then set v_msg := 'Error: parameters are not valid';
elseif p_vendor_id not in (select vendor_id from p_plants.vendors) then
    set v_msg := 'Error: vendor id parameter is not a vendor in our tables';
end if;
```

There is an example in the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html